# Coverting html javascript into iOS app through PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova

I did the following step to convert my html and javascript to make it compatible for iOS app using phonegap:

1. I uploaded the zipped file of my java script on phonegap.com and gave the relevant .p12 certificate along with the provising profile.
2. Now I downloaded the ipa file from there.
3. I tried to install this app through iTunes which did not installed desppite of waiting for couple of hours.

What can be the issue can anyone please tell me?

Is it something like that the provising profile used here should be for that particular device?

Comment: have  you  added your device in  provising profile.

Comment: ohh am sorry i skipped that step, but now when i did that i was given an error certificate doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i think  you have not added device in provising profile
```

1 Go to your Apple developer portal Click Devices to register your iOS device.
You need to connect your device to iTunes to obtain your UUID Click Certificate

**2**-Create a certificate for Production (to use PhoneGap Build, otherwise Development) Download the certificate

**3**- Convert the certificate to a p12 file . - Double-click the .cer file to open it in Key Chain Access.

Then click My Certificates under the category, Ctrl-click the certificate and export.
When you save the .p12 file, you are asked to create a password that you will need later.

**4**- Create a provision file on Apple developer portal, then download. Again, to make this work on PhoneGap Build, you need one for Distribution, otherwise Development. -
See more at: [link](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/converting-your-javascript-app-to-an-ios-app-w-phonegap/#sthash.JlCbZsny.dpuf)

Comment: I just followed your step and was given this error Error - Certificate doesn't match profile: The default keychain doesn't have an identity matching - You can fix this here                                                                                                     please help

Comment: are you able to run apps in iOS device? from the xcode

Comment: yes it worked fine now....something was wrong with the app id...thank you for the reply

Comment: check it step by step.let me know if issue @nikitasatnalika

Comment: if its solved your issue . mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.because Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved.@nikitasatnalika